# Restore marker initial position and zoom level in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

In Leaflet, I am trying to create a function that restores the initial position and zoom level of a layer containing coordinates. The code below

```
function refresh() {
    map.fitBounds(coordLayer.getBounds();
}
```

centers the marker but is zoomed in to the maxZoom I had set:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([lat, lon], 6);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png' {
    maxZoom: 13,
    minZoom: 2,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(map);
```

The default zoom level on page refresh is 6, but I don't know how to create a function that centers the marker at zoom level 6.

Answer (score 5):

Found a simple solution after reading the Documentation:

```
function refresh() {
map.setView([lat, lon], 6);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[With this var](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-zoom) you can set your Default Initial Zoom Level and [this getter](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-getzoom) should work on this.

Is this the answer you've been searching for?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to integrate that into the function